# strange integer behavior with gcc -O2

Tags: c++, c, gcc, integer, compiler-optimization

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void sanity_check(int x)
{
    if (x < 0)
    {
        x = -x;
    }
    if (x == INT_MIN)
    {
        printf("%d == %d\n", x, INT_MIN);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d != %d\n", x, INT_MIN);
    }
    if (x < 0)
    {
        printf("negative number: %d\n", x);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("positive number: %d\n", x);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    sanity_check(42);
    sanity_check(-97);
    sanity_check(INT_MIN);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the above program with `gcc wtf.c`, I get the expected output:

```
42 != -2147483648
positive number: 42
97 != -2147483648
positive number: 97
-2147483648 == -2147483648
negative number: -2147483648
```

However, when I compile the program with `gcc -O2 wtf.c`, I get a different output:

```
42 != -2147483648
positive number: 42
97 != -2147483648
positive number: 97
-2147483648 != -2147483648
positive number: -2147483648
```

Note the last two lines. What on earth is going on here? Is gcc 4.6.3 optimizing a bit too eagerly?

(I also tested this with g++ 4.6.3, and I observed the same strange behavior, hence the C++ tag.)

Comment: not feel comfortable to give advice for possibly much more experienced developer, but anyway it might be useful for not so experienced. If I see "strange" differences caused by only optimization level, the first thing I will look for is UB.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you do -(INT_MIN) you're invoking undefined behavior, since that result can't fit in an int.

gcc -O2 notices that x can never be negative and optimizes thereafter. It doesn't care that you overflowed the value since that's undefined and it can treat it however it wants.

Comment: There's an example in pedr0's answer. For some more see here: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html#signed_overflow

Comment: very thanks for the link! note that the first two paragraphs strongly imply logical fallacies of the kind "X is one possible way of doing Y, therefore X is required for Y". i stopped reading after that... :-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Can you be specific what formulations imply that kind of fallacy? I haven't found any in the first two paragraphs of either the "signed integer oveflow" part or the entire article.

Comment: Hmm, if overflow of signed integers weren't UB, you _couldn't_ substitute `x + 1 > x` with true if `x` is a signed integer, since it'd be false if `x == TYPE_MAX`. Or what am I missing? Concerning the second point, I don't know which loop optimisations are possible if it is known that a loop is finite, but not if it might be infinite, so I can't judge your claim or theirs there.

Comment: Re "what am i missing", i wouldn't want to speculate. the logic you present does not hold though: there is no connection between premise and conclusion. it is not the case that if for one case x + 1 > x does not hold, it can't be true in other cases. actually, in *most* cases x + 1 > x does hold: it holds in the *overwhelming* number of cases. so in order to make that single case prevent optimization, you have to remove all knowledge of x's value. to me, that is pretty obvious: i just think about "how would i have done it" and "how do other compilers do it". no problem.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Wait, what? If you have an `int x; /* some more code */ if (x + 1 > x) { /* do something */ } else { /* do something else */ } /* more code */`, the fact that overflow is UB allows the compiler to remove the `if` and completely eliminate the `else` branch. Weren't it UB, e.g. if wrapping was guaranteed, the compiler can't do that, unless it can prove that `x` cannot be `INT_MAX` at that place in the code.

Comment: @Daniel: with the "unless", your argument is empty. it is impossible for a human to walk without falling, unless it manages to stay upright. it cannot even breathe air, unless there is air to breathe. and regarding what i'm currently doing, it is quite impossible for me to eat dinner soon, unless i eat dinner soon.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm sure what you're writing makes sense to you, I fail to read it though. The point of that paragraph is that with UB, the compiler can make these substitutions even without proving that at that place in the program the values of the variables cannot be such that the substitution would be invalid. Without UB, it could _sometimes_ make the substitution, but not always. If you read the paragraph to imply that without UB, the compiler could _never_ make such substitutions, okay, but I don't understand the paragraph so.

Comment: i do "ead the paragraph to imply that without UB, the compiler could never make such substitutions", because that's the only way it makes sense as an argument in favor of using the UB to do unexpected surgery on the programmer's code. i do think that *if* it was meant to be clear about the assumption of "no value information", it would say that up front. so, all in all, given the impractical and thoroughly undesired nature of the alleged "optimization", my impression after reading the first two paragraphs of the linked article, was that it's designed as deception.

Answer (score 12):

I think this could help you, is from here :[here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

> -fstrict-overflow
>   Allow the compiler to assume strict signed overflow rules, depending on the language being compiled. For C (and C++) this means that overflow when doing arithmetic with signed numbers is undefined, which means that the compiler may assume that it will not happen. This permits various optimizations. For example, the compiler will assume that an expression like i + 10 > i will always be true for signed i. This assumption is only valid if signed overflow is undefined, as the expression is false if i + 10 overflows when using twos complement arithmetic. When this option is in effect any attempt to determine whether an operation on signed numbers will overflow must be written carefully to not actually involve overflow.
>   This option also allows the compiler to assume strict pointer semantics: given a pointer to an object, if adding an offset to that pointer does not produce a pointer to the same object, the addition is undefined. This permits the compiler to conclude that p + u > p is always true for a pointer p and unsigned integer u. This assumption is only valid because pointer wraparound is undefined, as the expression is false if p + u overflows using twos complement arithmetic.

See also the -fwrapv option. Using -fwrapv means that integer signed overflow is fully defined: it wraps. When -fwrapv is used, there is no difference between -fstrict-overflow and -fno-strict-overflow for integers. With -fwrapv certain types of overflow are permitted. For example, if the compiler gets an overflow when doing arithmetic on constants, the overflowed value can still be used with -fwrapv, but not otherwise.

The -fstrict-overflow option is enabled at levels -O2, -O3, -Os.